# Making a rule that only applies when the expression is NOT an argument?

Tags: replacement, core-language, rule, term-rewriting

I know we can make rules of the kind:

```
magic/:f_[x___,magic[a_],y___]:=f[x,arg[a],y]
```

This will replace `magic[a]` by `arg[a]` whenever `magic[a]` is the argument of a function.

Suppose I want `arg[a]` to be replaced by `a`, but only when `arg[a]` is NOT the argument of a function. Ie. I want a rule that applies only on top-level, only in those situations where the first pattern would not apply. Making `arg[a_] := a` is inadequate. In pseudocode it would be  `arg[a_] := a /; Not[FunctionArgument[arg[a]]]`.
Is this possible to achieve in Mathematica?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "top-level"? Do you actually mean when `arg[a]` is only at `Level` 1? In that case, you can use `Replace[expr, arg[a] -> a, {1}]` to repalce only at level 1. However, I suspect that that's not quite what you mean, because, for instance, `Replace[arg[a]^2 + arg[a], arg[a] -> a, {1}]` would yield `arg[a]^2 + a`, and I suspect that you would want the other `arg[a]` replaced as well.  Can you clarify? For instance, what kinds of expressions are you looking to make this replacement in?

Comment: No, actually, `Replace[expr, arg[a] -> a, {1}]` is correct as you described.  I'm not sure if or how it's possible to turn this kind of replace into a rewriting rule.  Ie. I want `arg[a]` to be automatically replaced by `a` whenever `arg[a]` is NOT in a pattern of the form  `f_[x___,arg[a_],y___]` . Which is not very often, but it can happen. I suspect the negation goes "against" the usual rules of defining transformation.

Comment: I wonder if this rule would work.  We could probably simplify it, but I think this might work. The idea is that `ReplaceAll` starts from the top level and if it changes a subexpression, it doesn't replace any subexpressions of the subexpression.  So we design a rule that matches a *general* expression at the top level:`(f_[x__, arg[a], y___] | f_[x___, arg[a], y__]) :> f[x, a, y]`

Comment: Although, that might also do essentially the same thing as `magic/:f_[x___,arg[a_],y___]:=f[x,arg[a],y]`. Actually, now that I think about it, I'm still a little confused about what you need.  Can you give some example inputs and outputs that show the problem cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, one way we could approach this is by inspecting the evaluation stack:

```
arg[a_] := a /; StackInhibit[Stack[] === {arg, RuleCondition}]
```

`StackInhibit` just means we don't have to also worry about matching `SameQ`, so it's not totally necessary. This could also be subverted by appropriate `StackBegin`s, but that could be viewed as either a bug or a feature: if we want to force `arg[a]` to "behave like a top level expression", surround it with `StackBegin`. There might be more robust, general, or elegant ways to get this same behavior.

Let's try it out:

```
arg[5]

(* Out: 5 *)

x := arg[5]

x

(* Out: 5 *)

f[arg[5]]

(* Out: f[arg[5]] *)
```

But there are some cases where it doesn't work as you might expect:

```
Null; arg[5]

(* Out: arg[5] *)

Block[{x}, arg[5]]

(* Out: arg[5] *)
```

I wonder if there's a way around this.

---

There is an ad-hoc way to apply a rule to every output expression, by setting `$Post`:

```
$Post = Replace[arg[a_] :> a];
```

(Note that `Replace` by default operates only on the whole expression, unlike `ReplaceAll` (`/.`), so we don't need to specify the level.)

While this will fix the examples above, it is local to a given kernel session, has to play nicely with potential other definitions of `$Post`, and is not a property of the head `arg`, so it might not be desirable.